# Como Emplear like en linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Quiero obtener un registro de un articulo existente en la base de datos, lo que hago es que en un textbox capturo el texto. El caso es que con el `==` me funciona para algunos artículos, pero para muchos de estos no, me genera un null reference, quiero probar `like` hasta el momento he intentado lo siguiente

```
var QueryArticulo = _db.articuloes.Where(s => s.nombre like "'%'+TextBoxArticulo.Text+'%'");
```

alguna forma de como incorporarlo o que otra cosa puedo usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo que quieres es utilizar un metodo como si fuera un like utiliza el metodo `contais` que te devolvera de acuerdo a los caracteres que le pases, deberia quedar asi tu codigo,

```
var QueryArticulo = _db.articuloes.Where(s => s.nombre.Contains(TextBoxArticulo.Text)).ToList();
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, lo logre resolver de una forma similar `var QueryArticulo = _db.articuloes.Where(s => s.nombre.Contains(TextBoxArticulo.Text));` pero marcare tu respuesta.

Comment: Ahora, no tengo muy claro que hace el `ToList` que utilizas

Comment: para que te devuelva una lista con los objetos que contienen esa condicion

Answer (score 0):

En este enlace podrán encontrar la respuesta a nivel detallado de mi pregunta, espero ayudarlos

https://th2tran.blogspot.com/2009/06/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize.html